# C split function creation using strtok_r - like perl and awk

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to write my own `split` function like in `perl` and `awk` using `strtok_r` function in `C` which creates array as well as returns number of elements in array, I tried something, but I didn't get concept of dynamic memory allocation properly, kindly someone correct me, also please put comments.

I believe that `strdup` takes care of memory allocation am I right ?

**Error : Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

This is what I tried so far

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>


 int split(char * str, char **fields, const char *sep)
 {
    char *copy = strdup(str), *tmp, *word;     
    int count=0;

    word = strtok_r(copy, sep, &tmp);
    while(word)
    {
                word=strtok_r(NULL, sep, &tmp);
        fields[count] = strdup(word);
        count++;    
    }

    return count;   
 }

 int main()
 {
         char string[80]="a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l"; 
         const char *sep = ","; 
         char **cols;  int i;           
     cols = malloc(strlen(string)+1*sizeof(char *));
    printf("%s\n",string);
    int n = split(string,cols,sep);
    printf("%s\t%d\n",string,n);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)printf("%s\t%s\n",string,cols[i]);
    free(cols);

    return 0;
 }
```

Thanks in advance for all volunteers

Comment: `cols` is not allocated, it doesn't point to any valid memory. Dereferencing it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant : whether this `cols = malloc(strlen(string)+1*sizeof(char *));` is right sir ?

Comment: @userXXX no, it isn't.

Comment: `cols = malloc(strlen(string)*sizeof(char *));` also need free each element of cols. and `word=strtok_r(NULL, sep, &tmp);` move to last of block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite a few beginner errors:

1) Allocate memory for `cols`, E.g. in `main()` before calling `split()`:

```
cols=malloc(sizeof *cols * 256);
```

Adjust the number 256 as you need or calculate it based on the no. of "," you have in `string`.

2) Your loop part is wrong in that you are tokenizing *again* before checking for NULL or storing the previous token:

```
  while(word)
    {
        word=strtok_r(NULL, sep, &tmp);
        fields[count] = strdup(word);
        count++;    
    }
```

Put the tokenizing as the last statement in loop:

```
  while(word)
    {
        fields[count] = strdup(word);
        count++;    
        word=strtok_r(NULL, sep, &tmp);
    }
```

3) You should also free `copy` in `split()` before returning. Otherwise, you program will have memory leak. Remember that `strdup` allocates memory for you (and you should check if it returns NULL as well), but you are responsible for `free`ing it.

```
free(copy);
```

And the same applies to the memory allocated for `cols[*]`. i.e. After printing the strings in `main()`, do:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
  free(cols[i]);
```

Although, it's not strictly necessary to free memory right before program terminates (as most modern operating systems will deallocate them anyway), it's a good practice to clean up yourself.

4) Use a standard prototype for `main()`, such as: `int main(int argc, char*argv[])` or `int main(void)`.

Comment: What to do if number of commas are unknown ?

Comment: You could count using `strchr()` to count commas (in a loop) and allocate exactly the number of pointers you want. Or use `realloc` (realloc, IMO, is a bit of overkill here but a possible way).

Comment: Sometimes there will be multiple separators like `cont char *sep =", |:-<>"`, any idea ?

Comment: 1) You could use realloc in that case or 2) count all delimiters (but extra care needed E.g. have to exclude if there are consecutive delimiters) and allocate memory.

Comment: Tried this inside function loop `fields = realloc(word,(count+1)*sizeof(char *));` no luck